# Caching images in a tableViewCell

Tags: rubymotion

wish someone can help me with this:

I have an app displaying remote data. The data consists of a json response containing a list of artitsts performing at some event.

Each artist has a picture I want to display in a tableView.

I'm looking for a optimized way to do this caching the images and creating the cells asynchronously

Here is what I have done so far:

My tableView

```
class LineupTableViewController < UITableViewController
  attr_accessor :artists
  #attr_accessor :table
  def init
    super
    self.title = 'Line-up'
    self.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
    self.view.styleId = 'lineUpView'
    self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.alloc.initWithTitle("LineUp", image: UIImage.imageNamed("112-group.png"), tag:2)    
    self
  end
  def viewWillAppear(animated)
    view.dataSource = view.delegate = self
    @artists = []
    App::Persistence['event']['artists'].each do |artist|
      @artists.push(Artist.new(artist)) unless artist["dj"]
    end

  end

  def viewDidLoad
    super

    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
  end

def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  artist = @artists[indexPath.row]
  ArtistCell.cellForArtist(artist, indexPath:indexPath, inTableView:tableView)      
end
def tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
  @artists.length
end
def tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
  detailViewController = ArtistsdetailViewController.alloc.initWithArtist(@artists[indexPath.row])   
  self.navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated:true)   
end

def tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
     80
end  
#def reloadRowForIndexPath(indexPath)
#  puts "indexPath.section #{indexPath.section}"
#  self.view.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath.indexPathForRow(indexPath.row, inSection:indexPath.section)], withRowAnimation:false)
#end



end
```

My custom cell

```
class ArtistCell < UITableViewCell
  attr_accessor :index_path
  CellId = "ArtistCellIdentifier"  
  def setSelected(selected, animated:animated)
    super
    # Configure the view for the selected state
  end

  def self.cellForArtist(artist, indexPath:indexPath, inTableView:tableView)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ArtistCell::CellId) || ArtistCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, reuseIdentifier:CellId)
      #puts "indexPath #{}"
      cell.index_path = indexPath
      cell.fillArtist(artist, inTableView:tableView)    
    cell
  end

  def fillArtist(artist, inTableView:tableView)
    #Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do      
     #  Dispatch::Queue.main.sync do
        self.textLabel.text = artist.name
        self.detailTextLabel.text = artist.country

        JMImageCache.sharedCache.imageForURL(NSURL.URLWithString(artist.picture), completionBlock:proc {
          |downloaded_image|      
            self.imageView.image = downloaded_image

        })

      # end
    #end     

  end
end
```

What I get now is:

- there is no image in displayed cells unless I tap them
- when I scroll down the view, the hidden cells' images are displayed, so when I scroll back to the top, all the images are displayed.

Any help solving this would be much appreciated
FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def fillArtist(artist, inTableView:tableView)

    self.textLabel.text = artist.name
    self.detailTextLabel.text = artist.country
    self.imageView.setImage(nil)

    JMImageCache.sharedCache.imageForURL(NSURL.URLWithString(artist.picture), completionBlock:proc { |downloaded_image|      
        self.imageView.image = downloaded_image
        self.setNeedsLayout
    })
  end
end
```

Explanation: setting NIL in the cell makes sure the new image is loaded. setNeedsLayout forces relayout thus displaying the image without the need to tap.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great.
Do you have any resources where I can get more reading than the rubymotion book?

Comment: Done.
It's working. Now looking for a way to make scrolling through the list smoother

Comment: What do you mean by 'smoother'?  Sure seems like your image load should be an async task that notifies when the image has been loaded (not familiar with JMImageCache myself) so you aren't waiting on a potentially slow operation.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the rest of the code. I also use JMImageCache and the scrolling is perfectly smooth. Must be something else.

Comment: By smoother I mean a nicer way. maybe playing with alpha to show the image progressively